# XSLT copy-of seems to add line feeds between nodes in some circumstances

Tags: html, xslt, xhtml

I am using xslt to transform xml into html.

Part of the incoming xml contains nodes that are copied directly to the output within **pre** tags using **xslt:copy-of**.

I have a problem in that part of the copied node has line feeds inserted where there are none in the original XML. The line feeds upset the formatting, because the pre tag is sensitive to line feeds in the html body.

I am using Microsoft Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0 to hold the XML and perform the transformation. I am using XSLT version 2.0 and have **indent="no" method="xml"** in the xsl:output node.

The specific circumstance in which a line feed is added seems to be when two html tags follow one another with intervening spaces and no other text. Here is the actual text of the XML node being transformed:

```
<span field='text'>
  <a href="aa">aa</a><a href="bb">bb</a>
  <a href="cc">cc</a> <a href="dd">dd</a>
  <a href="ee">ee</a>- -<a href="ff">ff</a>
</span>
```

For explanation, are three lines within the node. Each line contains two hyperlinks, the first with no intervening space, the second with an intervening space, and the third with intervening text that contains a space.

The relevant part of the transform is:

```
<pre style="margin-left: 2em" ><xsl:copy-of select=" span[@field='text'] "/></pre>
```

The output HTML text that is generated is:

```
<pre style="margin-left: 2em"><span field="text" xmlns=""><a href="aa">aa</a><a href="bb">bb</a>
<a href="cc">cc</a>
<a href="dd">dd</a>
<a href="ee">ee</a>- -<a href="ff">ff</a>
</span></pre>
```

The first line and the third line have been output as supplied, but the second line, in which the anchor tags have a single intervening space, has been split into two lines.

I have tried using the form `<xsl:copy-of select="span[@field='text']/node() " />` in the transform, but this removes all the line feeds so none of the layout is preserved.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this behaviour specific to Microsoft XML?

Any assistance you can give would be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. Some remarks: MSXML (even 6.0) is an XSLT 1.0 processor so using `version="2.0"` seems odd as all it does put the processor into forwards compatible mode resulting in suppressed error messages. And if you want to transform XML to HTML then why do you have output method `xml`? How do you load the XML into the MSXML DOM document, which `preserveWhitespace` setting do you use?

Comment: Hmm - thanks for your quick response. I was not aware that MSXML is not version 2. Regarding `output="XML"`, i want to generate XHTML (maybe I should have been more specific) and using `output="HTML"` does not work for this. Also I think there was a specific problem with `output="HTML"` which I can't remember right now.

Comment: The XML is constructed in memory by appending nodes from various sources. The specific node in question comes from a SQL database field that is parsed to convert some text into hyperlinks. The resulting text is loaded in the `<span>` element using `LoadXML` into a separate document, then the `documentElement` is appended to the master XML document prior to the transform. I have not used any `preserveWhitespace` setting. I have a lot of whitespace in the XSLT and think it would make the generated html longer than necessary. Maybe it can be done in a targeted way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the problem in http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014101201.html but when I set `preserveWhiteSpace = true` on the input DOM document, as done in http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014101203.html, the problem goes away.
So a complete test case showing how to solve the problem with preserveWhiteSpace is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var xmlMarkup = "<span field='text'>\n  <a href=\"aa\">aa</a><a href=\"bb\">bb</a>\n  <a href=\"cc\">cc</a> <a href=\"dd\">dd</a>\n  <a href=\"ee\">ee</a>- -<a href=\"ff\">ff</a>\n</span>";
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
xmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = true;
xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlMarkup);

var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
xslDoc.loadXML([
    '<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">',
    '<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>',
    '<xsl:template match="/">',
    '<pre>',
    '<xsl:copy-of select="span[@field = \'text\']"/>',
    '</pre>',
    '</xsl:template>',
    '</xsl:stylesheet>'].join('\n'));

document.getElementById('output').value = xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc);
}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
  <body>
  <textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>

</body>


</html>
```

and then the output, as tested in IE 11 on Windows 8.1, is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><pre><span field="text">
  <a href="aa">aa</a><a href="bb">bb</a>
  <a href="cc">cc</a> <a href="dd">dd</a>
  <a href="ee">ee</a>- -<a href="ff">ff</a>
</span></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. Setting `preserveWhiteSpace=true` on the XML document, as above, has worked perfectly.

Comment: Maybe I spoke too soon. Strangely, when `preserveWhiteSpace=true` is set, some of the generated html elements that are empty are converted to the short form. So `<textarea name="abc" ></textarea>` becomes `<textarea name="abc" />`. This is not recognised in the browser as valid html. I tried changing the output method to html but the same stil happens. I have implemented a (hopefully temporary) work-around by putting a single period in empty textareas. I am hunting for the solution to that one, maybe that should be a separate question. (I am using Chrome)

Comment: A better workaround for now is to include a single space within a text node like so: `<textarea rows="10" cols="80" name="text" ><xsl:text> </xsl:text></textarea>`. Just putting a space between the textarea tags does not work, nor does putting in an empty text node.

Comment: In general if you use XSLT 1.0 and want to generate text/html output then using `method="html"` and no namespace for the HTML elements is the way to go. If you use output `xml` then you get XML serialization and in XML `<textarea/>` is the same as `<textarea></textarea>`. So if you want to send text/html to a browser then with XSLT 1.0 my suggestion is to use the output method="html" and no namespace on your HTML elements.

Comment: I found out what the original problem was with using ouput method HTML. In some cases the generated output is loaded as an XML document to be used within a web page with XMLHttp. When the method is set to html the output omits the closing / on some empty items, as in `<input type="hidden" name="fff" value="abc" />` becomes `<input type="hidden" name="fff" value="abc" >` without any closure at all. This then fails to be loaded in XMLHttp.

Comment: But what puzzles me is that the output is correct (i.e. `<textarea...> </textarea>` when `preserveWhiteSpace=false` and incorrect (i.e. <textarea .. />` when `preserveWhiteSpace=true`. Output method is XML in both cases. That seems to me to be the opposite of what would be expected.

Comment: Also, as noted above, changing the output method to HTML in this case does not fix the problem.

Comment: It seems to be a different problem and as I said, with XML both `<textarea/>` and `<textarea></textarea>` are the correct serialization of an empty element. And `html` output method only applies to HTML elements in no namespace so a change of the output method does not ensure that HTML serialization is used for empty elements in a namespace. I think you need to post a new question with details, it is not possible to resolve that in comments of this answer.

Comment: OK Thanks for all your help. Anyway, I have a working version with a small work-around so I am quite happy now. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is this behaviour specific to Microsoft XML?

That's easy to find out: compare your results to say Saxon 6.5.5 here: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2BX

Note the effect of adding the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` instruction: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2BX/1

--
P.S. I am not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish here with the `<pre>` tags, since the **rendered** result of the first version above is:

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for this reply. It looks like Saxon generates different output from MSXML - after the transform the original line formatting has been preserved. Re your P.S., I am using the `<pre>` tags because the database field that is being transformed is plain text that has been laid out with spaces, tabs and line feeds, and the `<pre>` tag preserves the layout when being displayed.

Comment: @JohnRC That's not exactly what you show us here, since the whitespaces are between *elements*, not within "real" text nodes. Perhaps you should look for an entirely different method to achieve (whatever it is) - for example, forcing the DB to output the field contents as CDATA?

Comment: I did try using CDATA but this is sent through to the HTML as text - i.e. the  HTML tags are converted from `<a ..` to `&lt;a ..` etc. I tried `disable-output-escaping' but to no avail.

Comment: @JohnRC "*I tried 'disable-output-escaping' but to no avail.*" Not sure what to say to that, because that's precisely what `disable-output-escaping` is meant to do.

Comment: @micheal.hor I found out what I was doing wrong. Having generated a CDATA section, I needed to change the xslt to use `value-of` instead of `copy-of`. So, `<xsl:value-of select="span[@field='name']/node()" ` with `disable-output-escaping="yes"` works fine. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @JohnRC That's good, because using CDATA is a much more robust solution for the described scenario.